# What is permissionId in Google API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-client

I am trying to replicate the JavaScript client library example shown on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update#examples. There is a reference to `permissionId`. How do I get this, I've looked everywhere, and my assumption is I am missing something dead obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a REST API such as Drive, every resource has a unique ID. Permissions are the same. When you create a permission, its ID is returned within the response. If you list permissions, you'll see it there. See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions

Comment: Thanks, @pinoyyid. My goal is to create a Fusion Table and update the share setting to "Anyone who has the link can view." Am I barking up the wrong tree by pursuing permissions? I did not see a way to modify the share settings through the Fusion Tables API specifically. Thanks again.

Comment: so here's the thing... "permissionId" is a string.  The link you pointed me to, I don't see anywhere it's listing a bunch of strings which are permissions. When I want to call `update` I have no idea what I should set the value of this string to be, and neither the API page for `update` nor the linked page give me any clue.

Comment: and FWIW I'm trying to change ownership of the file, so I would assume it would be something like "OWNER" or something.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking that permissions are properties of a file (a bit like in *nix for example). They aren't . 
Permissions are objects and as such, each Permission has a unique, opaque identifier, the permissionId. In order to find the permissionId of a particular permission, eg. in order to update it, you can call https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list in order to obtain a list of permissions with their permissionIds.